# Remove field in the form : only works for "url", not for "email"?

Tags: forms, email, comment-form

I would like to remove the email field in the comment form. It works for `url` but not for `email` : the email field is still there. Do you know why?

```
<?php
function url_filtered($fields)
{
  if(isset($fields['url'])) {
    unset($fields['url']);
  }
  if(isset($fields['email'])){
     unset($fields['email']);
  }
  return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'url_filtered');
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<?php
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'wpse53687_filter_fields');
/**
 * Unsets the email field from the comment form.
 */
function wpse53687_filter_fields($fields)
{
    if(isset($fields['email']))
        unset($fields['email']);
    return $fields;
}
```

One reason that it could be failing on your theme is that  args were passed into `comment_form`. Specifically, the theme author passed in a `fields` key into the [`$args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form#.24args).

As the filter name (`comment_form_default_fields`) implies, the fields are only defaults.

Fortunately there is another filter! `comment_form_field_{$name}`.  Just hook in and return false and it should get rid of the email field.

```
<?php
add_filter('comment_form_field_email', '__return_false');
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! so is there any way to directly edit the code in the form? (without using these filters?)

Comment: No, not really. The `comment_form` is usually what gets used in themes.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'remove_email');
function remove_email($val) {
    $val['email'] = '';
    return $val;    
}
```