# How to hide and disable URL and email fields from comments?

Tags: comments, comment-form, spam

How can I hide and completely disable (in case of bots) the URL and email fields in comments?

There are a few free plugins that seem to do this, but most of them only hide the URL field and not the email field, and anyway for such a small function I think it could just be added to theme functions.php.

Note: I know this prevents Gravatar from working properly.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I found some [relevant functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953160/how-can-remove-email-and-website-in-comments-wordpress). Keep in mind it's probably better to separate these into different functions, and if your WordPress theme gives you any trouble, [check this out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53687/remove-field-in-the-form-only-works-for-url-not-for-email).

```
// disable url field
function disable_comment_url($fields) {
    if(isset($fields['url']))
        unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'disable_comment_url');

// disable email field
function disable_comment_email($fields) {
    if(isset($fields['email']))
        unset($fields['email']);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'disable_comment_email');
```

Also be sure to visit Settings >> Discussion and uncheck the "Comment author must fill name and email" option to avoid user comments being rejected upon submission.